# Count occurrences with a BEGIN/END statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, vim, numbering

I have a list of numbers:

```
2
1
3
2
2
2
1
```

First I had a filelog. I extracted all the ID. Now, how do I  count the occurrences of each number and display it like this?
(the first one is the number, the second number is the occurrence of the number)

```
2,4
1,2
3,1
```

I had maybe an idea:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{print "count", "lineNum"}{print gsub(/t/,"") "\t" NR}' file
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Is your question related to [tag:vim], perhaps in a way you didn't make explicit?

Comment: What are the BEGIN and END statements you reference in the title of your question?

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
echo "$numbers" | sort | uniq -c | awk -v OFS=, '{print $2,$1}' | sort -t, -k2nr
```

If you have questions about how this works, the most self-educational way to pick it apart is to execute it in pieces:

```bsh
echo "$numbers" | sort
echo "$numbers" | sort | uniq -c 
# and so on
```

And of course, read the man pages for sort and uniq

---

With GNU awk, you can

```bsh
echo "$numbers" | gawk '
  {count[$1]++}
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    OFS = ","
    for (thing in count) print thing, count[thing]
  }
'
```